# Google OAuth 2.0 Callback URL

Tags: url, callback, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have an iOS application which authenticates with Google's servers via OAuth 2.0. I have just one problem, my app doesn't seem to respond to the callback URL. I have set the callback URL correctly in my code but no response.

I was just wandering if anyone knows how to change the callback URL on the Google OAuth API Console because right it is some random URL which doesn't seem to work for me:

```
urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the oob URI with an embedded view, or you can rely on the user to copy and paste the code.

But on iOS you have a better option, you can use a custom scheme based on the bundle id (or on the client id):
https://plus.google.com/111487187212167051233/posts/AztHNnQh7w6

Comment: Hi, thats really good. I tired that but after getting the token and redirect URI I get error 404....